# Pitagora's theorem in python game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So Im working on pygame game, and i would like that, enemies would take shortest way into player, based on pitagora's theorem, but i dont know how to do it. I tried by making by statement while enemy.x != player.x: enemy.x -= 2, but id doenst work

Could somebody help?